#  multiple recursion

Tags: c++, c

I have a doubt that ,inside a block if the same function is called two or more than two times recursively,then what is the order of execution?

e.g.:in case of mergesort ,for partition if i do like this

```
mergesort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
int mid;
if(low<high)
{
mid=(low+high)/2;
mergesort(a,low,mid);
mergesort(a,mid+1,high);
merge(a,low,high,mid);
}
```

then 
(1) will mergesort(a,low,mid), mergesort(a,mid+1,high) and merge(a,high,mid) be called one by one if condition (low

(2) Or will the call to merge(a,low,mid) will go on recursively and then after merge(a,mid+1,high) is executed recursively and at last merge(a,low,mid) is executed .

I know this is very simple for you skilled guys,but please do a favour to me by answering this.

Answer (score 6):

```
                        merge_main_call_0
                              |
                              |
              +-----------------+------------------+
              |                                    |
              +                                    +
       merge_1_call_1                         merge_2_call_4
              +                                    +
              |                                    |
    +---------+---------+                +---------+---------+
    |                   |                |                   |
    +                   +                +                   +
 merge_1_call_2   merge_2_call_3     merge_1_call_5    merge_2_call_6
 (here `if' is false)                     (here `if' is false)
```

This shows the call tree. The first function will be called first whenever the `if` is true at some level or recursion. When the `if` is false in some level or recursion, it will go back to the last function call (the one from which it was called), which will start the execution after the first function call, which will call the second function. The second function then repeats the same thing.

In the above diagram `merge_1_call_n` means that the merger function 1 is called the nth time.

When the first time the `if` condition of will become false in some recursive level it will return back to the last recursive level and start executing from where it left from, which will then call the second function. Similarly, recursively when at this level this function call will return, it will execute the merge function, and then the control returns from this level to the last recursive level.

It is very important to understand what a recursion level is. To do this draw the first function call as the left most child of a n-ary tree and the last call as the rightmost child, and try to form a tree like structure. The depth first search (pre-order) will result in the call sequence of the functions.

**UPDATE**

For the recursive call process going on, check out the [Call Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and [Activation Records](http://Activation%20Records%20and%20the%20Stack)

Comment: recursion trees are immensely helpful to understand recursion.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, if `low < high`, then the `mergesort()` function will be called *twice* and the `merge()` function *once*. However, because this function is recursive, calls to `mergesort()` might call itself more times (depending on the values passed to it).

Comment: :Thanks.Can you please tell me in which order will the functions be called?And how will they be executed?I am having misconception with recursion.It will be really very kind if you clear my doubt with help of stack mechanism or any other mechanism of implementation of recursion.Or if you can please give me the link to clear my doubts on recursion.

Comment: @gautamkumar: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631447/how-recursion-works-in-c

Comment: @aamir:can you please tell what are the things i.e. argment,return value etc that are pushed in stack?Please explain.

Comment: @gautam kumar: they are not practically pushed, a new stack frame is created, by manipulating the base pointer register and the stack pointer register,which points to the new stack frame. You should have a look at function activation records: http://enel.ucalgary.ca/People/Norman/engg335_fall1998/activ_rec/

Comment: @phoxis:Please answer last part of the question i.e. "when the if condition is true then all the three functions will be called one by one or the call to first function i.e. mergesort(a,low,mid) will be called repeatedly.please clear my doubt."

Comment: one by one,normally.But when the first function is called, but as it is calling the same function (itself) with new values, a new stack frame is called and this function code is re-executed,in which case again only the first function is called.When the function calls will return from the deeper recursion depth to a certain depth, then the second function will be called.Look at the diagram in my answer.Note the function number and the order when it is called.Trace manually.Here in this context the "repeatedly" does not have iterative effect, because the functions are called in different depths.

Answer (score 0):

Two function calls means that the function will be called two times, if the condition is true.

Comment: :Thanks.Can you please tell me in which order will the functions be called?And how will they be executed?I am having misconception with recursion.It will be really very kind if you clear my doubt with help of stack mechanism or any other mechanism of implementation of recursion.Or if you can please give me the link to clear my doubts on recursion.

Comment: The first will be called first. The second will be called second. Any other calls happen in a separate stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension of @phoxis's answer showing the call stack (as he mentioned it in his answer). I think understanding the call stack is how you can make sense of the tree:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In main merge function if *if* condition is true then first merge() is called. Compiler saves everything on stack and call main merge again. It keeps repeating this until *if* condition is false. As soon as *if* condition is false compiler retreat back by popping from stack. It will keep popping from stack until it comes back to the very first merge() saved on stack. After popping and calling this merge it will go on to second merge and will repeat the whole process. Similary with the last merge.

So the Order is:
First Merge, then keep repeating until *if* fails, second merge, keep repeating..., third merge

Comment: you are right..my explanation is wrong ! I guess I should get some sleep now