# Returns in Recursive Function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm a little confused here. Let's look at the following code:

```
bool testing(int i) {

    if((i%2)==0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        --i;
        testing(i);
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I do `testing(5)`, I was expecting the function to return true because at some point, `5` will become `4`, so `4 % 2 == 0`, so the function will return `true` but it just wasn't the case. What's wrong?

Comment: did u step through in a debugger? Then u can see whats happening

Comment: I think you should have `return testing(i)`. The way it is it calls `testing()` but it continues through and returns false.

Comment: As an optimization note, you're better off doing `if((i&1)==0)` instead of `if((i%2)==0)`. Also better off doing `return testing(i-1)` instead of `--i ; return resting(i)`, though the optimizer will optimize that one out anyway.

Comment: @iAdjunct. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @iAdjunct `i&1` and `i%2` are not equivalent for negative numbers.

Comment: @NeilKirk - Good point. I interpreted his test as "checking for odd numbers," in which case this is what he wants, but they are different. Interestingly, though, I just checked: `((-3)%2)` in C++ and Swift give `-1`, but python 2.7.10 gives `1`.

Comment: @iAdjunct The sign of a modulus operation using negative numbers is defined differently between languages and before C++11 was implementation-defined as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of *recursion* is when **a function calls itself, directly or indirectly**. 
The function in your code will become recursive if it is modified to:

```
bool testing(int i){
    // test if even, if so return true
    if((i % 2) == 0){
        return true;
    // otherwise decrement and test again
    }else{
        // at this point the function calls itself with decremented argument
        return testing(--i);
    }
    // I doubt that this case will be ever returned  
    // more likely your function will return "true" or run "forever" decrementing
    return false;
}
```

To avoid infinite cycles you need a *base case*,  **termination condition that produces result without recursion**. 
 For example if `i` becomes very small  or negative you return `false`.

```
bool testing(int i){
    // base case
    if(i < 0) return false;
    // rest of the function
    if((i % 2) == 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return testing(--i);
    } 
}
```

Making it a bit more concise, you finally have three cases:

```
bool testing(int i){
    // base case
    if(i < 0) return false;
    // test if even
    if((i % 2) == 0) return true;
    // recursion step
    return testing(--i);
}
```

For further reading, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631447/how-recursion-works-in-c/30153559#30153559)

Comment: By optimizing you mean remove the curly brackets? You also don't need the last `else`.

Comment: @Emz you are right, the code is written more clearly and concisely, not optimized and the `else` is, indeed, not needed. Thanks :)

Comment: I recommend having a read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java this question.

Comment: @Emz  (personal opinion) _curly braces_ could be omitted if there is a single statement which could be put in the same line, after the _flow control statement_. There are some examples in "the books" omitting _curly braces_ and using _indentation_ on the next line "python style", but that is really ambiguous. If there is a larger _block of code_ it should be enclosed.

Answer (score 5):

You should `return testing(i);` instead of just `testing(i);`

Comment: Yes it is unreachable.  That's a separate issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Because of you only call `testing(i)` function. That's why it's not call recursively.

you should write `return testing(i)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't bubble up the final return value; you need to use return on the recursive call. Additionally, you can simplify the pre-decrement:

`return testing(--i);`

Answer (score 0):

it returns false because its return value is overridden by the last statement of "return false".