# Function returns wrong value but is able to print the correct value in a simple program to count number of steps needed to reach a point

Tags: c++

I was practicing coding problems online and in this problem I needed to print the number of steps a person(initially at x=0) needed to reach a destination(say x=5). The person can move (1,2,3,4,5) units forward in one step. So I wrote the following function.

```
int stepcounter(int &n, int step){
if (n == 0)
{

    return step;
}
vector<int> arr = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

for (auto &y : arr)
{
    if (n < y)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        step++;
        n = n - y;
        break;
    }
}

stepcounter(n, step);}

int main(){

int a;
cin >> a;
int s = 0;
cout << stepcounter(a, s);}
```

When you input say, for example 5 you get a 6422216 as the answer which is obviously incorrect.
But if you change

```
cout<<stepcounter(a,s);
```

to

```
stepcounter(a,s);
```

and change the if statement in the condition to

```
if (n == 0){
    cout<<step;
    return step;}
```

it works.
why is it so?

Comment: Your for loop doesn't have a return statement. Make sure you add a return statement for the case when none of the condition and for loop is run. Otherwise flowing off the end of a non-void returning function without return is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Also, turn on all warnings. See [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. In particular, if you don't `return` a value but the prototype says you should, then all bets are off.

Comment: @JasonLiam any suggestions what should I return and where should I add the statement so it does not interfere with the desired output of program?

Comment: @misterlister12 There are also questions on SO that address this. For example, [Returns in Recursive Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215194/returns-in-recursive-function-in-c). There are many more questions like this. You can search something like : *"what to return in a recursive function"*.

Comment: Why is `n` a reference? It's never used after the function returns.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub