# Please explain the working of this C program

Tags: c, function, output, function-calls

```
#include<stdio.h>

 void func1(int n)
 {
  if(n==0) return;
  printf("%d",n);
  func2(n-2);
  printf("%d",n);
 }

 void func2(int n)
 {
  if(n==0) return;
  printf("%d",n);
  func1(++n);
  printf("%d",n);
 }

void main()
{
    func1(5);
}
```

Output : 53423122233445

I don't understand the flow of control that is happening in this code leading to the above output. can someone please explain. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you ever dealt with recursion in programming before?

Comment: No. Is that what it is ?

Comment: Check out recursion in c. You can check different site's (Eg: Tutorialspoint)

Comment: I understand the recursion in which a function calls itself. Not the one that includes 2 functions.

Comment: `func2` needs a forward declaration of `void func2(int)` in order for this to be valid C.

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631447/how-recursion-works-in-c) to understand recursion a lot better.

Comment: The program won't compile because of [`void main()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: @Schwern I have defined the function before main so I don't think there is a need for a forward declaration.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala its a working code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `void main()` can be used. Sure it's not the correct signature, but it will work.

Comment: If you step through the code, you will see how it works.  As for the meaning of the two functions, you are probably in a better place than we to explain this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. I will now look at it from the angle of recursion. Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: @maheshRao No, `void main` is non-standard C. See 5.1.2.2.1 of the standard. Lots of things can be used but don't work will compile. It only "works" without compiler flags set to check against the standard, but it's Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Schwern Thats what I meant :P, but it's not like it wont work in this case.

Comment: When ever you not able to detect flow, use gdb and execute step by step. Which is real friend of a c programmer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes easier to understand if we annotate each `printf` so we can tell what number is from what part of the program. I'm also going to change the starting condition to 3 so we can walk through the whole thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func2(int);

void func1(int n)
{
    if(n==0) return;
    printf("func1 before: %d\n",n);
    func2(n-2);
    printf("func1 after: %d\n",n);
}

void func2(int n)
{
    if(n==0) return;
    printf("func2 before: %d\n",n);
    func1(++n);
    printf("func2 after: %d\n",n);
}

int main()
{
    func1(3);
}
```

That produces:

```
func1 before: 3
func2 before: 1
func1 before: 2
func1 after: 2
func2 after: 2
func1 after: 3
```

1. func1(3) prints 3 and calls func2(1).
2. func2(1) prints 1 and calls func1(2).
3. func1(2) prints 2 calls func2(0).
4. func2(0) returns immediately.

Now we've hit the bottom of the recursion. At this point we've built up a stack of function calls.

1. func1(3)
2. func2(1)
3. func1(2)

Once func2(0) returns, the call to func1(2) picks up where it left off and we work through the stack from the bottom up.

5. func1(2) prints 2 and returns to func2(1).
6. func2(1) prints 2, because it incremented n, and returns to func1(3).
7. func1(3) prints 3 and returns to main().
8. main() returns and the program exits.

Answer (score 2):

I have found through teaching students how recursion works with local variables is that the easiest way to understand it is if you do exactly what the computer does,
- process it step by step , and write down what gets called, and when variable values change

for example:

```
main
  func1(5)
    n=5
    printf  5
    func2(5-2)
      n=3
      print 3
      ++n
      n=4
      func1(4)
        n=4
        print 4
        func2(4-2)
          n=2
          print 2
          ++n
          n=3
          func1(3)
            n=3
            print 3
            func2(3-2)
              n=1
              print 1
              ++n
              n=2
              func1(2)
                n=2
                print 2
                func2(2-2)
                  n=0
                  if n==0 => return
                print 2
              print 2
            print 3
          print 3
        print 4
      print 4
    print 5
  //done
```

You will also need to understand that within each function call,
the changes to 'n' within a function do not change the earlier 
value from where it was called.

you can see this better if you imagine the computer doing something like this:
where every function call creates a new set of variables on the a stack,
and when a function returns, its variables are deleted off the stack.

```
stack: (empty)

main
  func1(5) ==> push n='5' on stack, then jump to func1()
    stack is now { n=5 }
    so n is 5
    print 5
    func2(5-2) ==> push 'n=3' on stack, then jump to func2()
      stack is now { n=3 } , { n=5 }
      so n is 3
      print 3
      ++n
      stack is now { n=4 } , { n=5 }
      func1(4) ==>  push 'n=4' on stack then jump to func1()
        stack is now { n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
        so n is 4
        print 4
        func2(4-2) ==> push 'n=2' on stack then jump to func()
          stack is now  {n=2}, {n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
          ++n
          stack is now {n=3}, {n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
          ...etc...
           .....
            ....
            stack is eventually {n=0} {n=2}, {n=2}, {n=2} ,{n=1} {n=3}, {n=3}, {n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
            after func(2-2) is called
            then:
              if n==0 => return;
            the return pops one item {n=0} off the stack, so
            stack is then {n=2}, {n=2}, {n=2} ,{n=1} {n=3}, {n=3}, {n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
            print 2
            return (deletes {n=2})
          stack is then {n=2}, {n=2} ,{n=1} {n=3}, {n=3}, {n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
          print 2
         return (deletes {n=2})
       stack is then {n=2} ,{n=1} {n=3}, {n=3}, {n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
       print 2
       return (deletes {n=2})
     stack is then {n=1} {n=3}, {n=3}, {n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
     print 1
     return (deletes {n=1})
    stack is then {n=3}, {n=3}, {n=4} , { n=4 } , { n=5 }
   print 3
```

and so on until it finishes and the last '5' is printed out.